# Using Xpath to take more element of the same type

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to take all the answer in this page, structured for example with author name and text of the answer.

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20151007080620AAVNtY1

If i use this code

```
 item = YahooItem()
 text_to_gain = hxs.xpath('//a[contains(@class,"uname Clr-    b")]/text()').extract()
    if text_to_gain:
        item['author']= str(text_to_gain[0]).strip()
    else:
        item['author']= "Anonymous"

    item['type']="Answer"

    text_to_gain = hxs.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"ya-q-full-text")][@itemprop="text"]/text()').extract()
    if text_to_gain:
        item['text']= str(text_to_gain[0]).strip()
    else:
        item['text']= "NULL"
  yield item
```

I take only one element.
I Try also to change hxs or use a iterator for example:

```
all_answer = hxs.xpath('//li[contains(@class,"Cf Py-14 ya-other-answer Pend-14 ")]').extract()
```

But not works

Comment: Can you edit your post to add a specific question? It's tough to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code of your spider?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the answers and relative authors with the expressions below.
This expression selects all the answers on the page, including the best answer

```
all_answers = hxs.xpath("descendant::*[@itemtype='https://schema.org/Answer']");
```

Now iterate on for each answer `answ`, and the following xpath expressions (executed relatively to each `answ` node) will select the text and the author, respectively

```
text = hxs.xpath(answ,"descendant::*[@itemprop='text']");
author = hxs.xpath(answ,"//a[starts-with(@class,'uname')]");
```